# Is it possible to recreate behavior of kotlin.Function interface to have multiple parameters?

Tags: generics, kotlin

When we want to use interface `kotlin.Function` it is possible to do something like this:

```
import kotlin.Function1
import kotlin.Function2
.......................
import kotlin.FunctionN
```

And then we can create `FunctionN` like following:

```
val funcN : FunctionN<Type1, Type2, ..., TypeN+1> = {t1, t2, ..., tN -> tN+1}
```

For example with N = 2, we can make function like this:

```
val func2 : Function2<Int, Int, String> = {i1, i2 -> "$i1 + $i2 = ${i1+i2}"}
```

This works for any number so they didn't write a separate function for each number but they are somehow doing it dynamically, and now I wonder if it is possible to replicate that kind of behavior and create some interface/class which works in similar way or it is only `Function` specific.

I tried searching online but couldn't find nothing on that, most likely because I don't even know how to call it.

Also had a look at source code but it is just empty interface:

```
/**
 * Represents a value of a functional type, such as a lambda, an anonymous function or a function reference.
 *
 * @param R return type of the function.
 */
public interface Function<out R>
```

So I assume they are doing all the magic somewhere else and wonder if anyone knows if is it possible to do it, and maybe can provide some information on how to do it.

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/functions/Functions.kt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't do it dynamically, they just have a separate function for each number, that's it.

You can't reach dynamic arguments count behavior for your classes or interfaces. You can pass varargs, but it's not something you want. However, you can try to reach something very similar using code generation, using intellij idea or annotation processing.